# Hosting angular app with firebase or heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, heroku, firebase-hosting

I hosted my angular website in firebase platform, but the problem is the domain name (website name). It is something like https://www.xxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com or in heroku https://www.xxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com

I want to use the domain name that I bought recently from godaddy, such as: www.mycompanyname.com and tell firebase hosting or heroku hosting to use this name rather than their name!

Is it possible to do so?

Thanks

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain

Comment: same goes for heroku, you can set custom domain to it.